# LINQPad - default db schema

Tags: linqpad

I'm connected to a ms sql database, and it has two set of tables, both with different schemas; 'xxx' and 'dbo'.

LINQPad assumes that my schema is 'dbo', but default schema for my group is 'xxx'. This causes the query to fail:

```
SomeTable.Take(10)
```

The generated SQL does not apply any schema information (this is the generated SQL);

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 [t0].Id, [t0].Name from [SomeTable] as [t0]
```

I want the query to run against the table in schema 'dbo', not 'xxx'. My question is; is it possible to specify 'dbo' as schema in the connection, or in the query?
The tables have different names for foreign and primary keys, but the columns are equal.

Comment: All schemas should appear in the treeview on the left. Is it somehow omitting the 'dbo' schema objects?

Comment: Yes, the tables from schema xxx appears in the treeview, and are prefixed with xxx_ as usual. It appears to me that the generated SQL is run against the 'dbo' schema (schema is not specified in the generated sql), but the default schema for my user, or the group that have access, is 'xxx'. Since the tables from 'xxx' and 'dbo' have some differences in PK and FK names, the query fails. I was hoping I could set the schema somehow. Could it be that LINQPad has something from the connection cached in a file somewhere? I've tried to refresh bot the connection and DB in LINQPad